# “Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed” (errno 150) : Laravel migration

Tags: laravel

When I migrate my DB, I got this error. Below is my coding:

**Code**:

```html
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('active')->default(1)->nullable();
            $table->double('code');
            $table->integer('unit')->default(1);
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->double('price');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

        });
    }
```

Error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `reochi`.`products` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`))

Comment: do you have categories table created?

Comment: @Dino Numić yes, Sir. Already.  Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: This schema worked for me. So the only thing that came to my mind was the order of the migrations.

Comment: @Dino Numić Ok Thank you Sir,now I can solve them because of the order of migration